# Tumblr with webview

Tags: android, webview

In my app i want to post image to tumblr.So i follow the tumblr api and i used the the sample from the github.This is the github address "https://github.com/RobertSzkutak/AndroidExamples".
And every thing is fine to upload the image successfully in tumblr. But in this sample they are using browser to open tumblr login page and authentication.But my question is how to use webview instead of browser.I google alot,but i did not find any solution.So please guide me how to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a new Activity and create a webview in onCreate(), you may pass the initial URL as an argument.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);

    setContentView(webview);

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(URL);
    webview.loadUrl(url);
}
```

then launch the activity where required

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), InAppBrowserActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(InAppBrowserActivity.URL, oauthTask.getUrl());
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, request_code);
```